# Whats the best way save a users last route location using express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

Consider a simple serverside node app.

```
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/path1",function(req,res) {
...
});
router.get("/path2",function(req,res) {
...
});
```

What's a great way to save the user's last location using localStorage or Cookies or anything? i.e.) [www.somewebpage.com/path1](http://www.somewebpage.com/path1) or [www.somewebpage.com/path2](http://www.somewebpage.com/path2)

I was hoping for something like

```
router. <forAllPaths>(o => {
localStorage.setItem(<...set url code>);
})
```

Comment: @ControlAltDel A cookie I think would be a bad idea because it is not unique and if another user tries to login on the same browser they will be redirected to the previous users route.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use redis and in each route you generate a middleware that stores or updates the last route used

```
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient();

const middleware = async (res, req, next) => {
   client.set(userId, req.originalUrl);
   next()
}

client.on("error", error => {
  console.error(error);
});

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/path1", middleware, async (req,res) => {

});

router.get("/path2", middleware, async (req,res) => {

});
```